# Fat arrow function throwing error "expression expected"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am setting up my server.js file in angular following a tutorial. In the tutorial he has no errors while my fat arrow funtion is saying "expression expected". I am new to javascript and mainly know Java.

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var http = require(http);
var app = express();

var api = require('./server'/api);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.use('/', api);

app.get('*'), (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "dist/index.html"));
}

var port = precess.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, () => console.log("Server is running"));
```

Comment: I don't see how your question is related to AngularJS or Typescript. However, I can see node.js / express code here. Please fix your question tags.

Answer (score 3):

I can see you've got a few errors:

`var http = require(http);` should be `var http = require('http');`

`var api = require('./server'/api);` should be `var api = require('./server/api');`

(both missing `'`)

`var port = precess.env.PORT || '3000';` should be `var port = process.env.PORT || '3000';`
(typo in process)

and, `app.get(...` should be

`app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "dist/index.html"));
})`

(the end bracket is in the wrong place)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the bracket here

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "dist/index.html"));
}
```

Also you need to reposition your quote mark here to be at the end of the string

```
var api = require('./server/api');
```

Also, which version of node are you using, as there is a chance arrow functions are not [supported](http://node.green/)?

[image]

Comment: npm version 5.6.0. I fixed the quote thanks. I made the changes but still have same errors

Answer (score 1):

You have an error on the port property:

```
var port = precess.env.PORT || '3000';
```

change it to

```
var port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
```

Change the word precess to process.